# how to customize UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my app I want to change the default look of a `UITextField`. I want it to look like a rectangle. I.E. how can I avoid the rounded edge of a `UITextField` ?

Answer (score 3):

In the Inspector, you can change the border style:

[image]

If you want something fancy, you can also change the background image:

[image]

If you aren't using the Interface Builder, you can easily change either of these attribute programmatically in `viewDidLoad`.